# Streaming video .mp4 H.264 baseline not working on some videos

Tags: java, android, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming

I use server to stream recorder videos on Android phones and play them in Android app later. However I noticed that I am not able to play all videos, I used ffmpeg to see if there is any difference in recorded videos and where the issue might be.
That is an example of loading and playing video:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'w1.mp4':


Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2019-01-07T15:38:52.000000Z
    com.android.version: 8.1.0
  Duration: 00:00:04.94, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5003 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt470bg/smpte170m), 720x480, 4951 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2, 27.71 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2019-01-07T15:38:52.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 8000 Hz, mono, fltp, 48 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-01-07T15:38:52.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
            "profile": "Baseline",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "444929/24660000",
            "codec_tag_string": "avc1",
            "codec_tag": "0x31637661",
            "width": 720,
            "height": 480,
            "coded_width": 720,
            "coded_height": 480,
            "has_b_frames": 0,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "3:2",
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": 30,
            "color_range": "tv",
            "color_space": "smpte170m",
            "color_transfer": "smpte170m",
            "color_primaries": "bt470bg",
            "chroma_location": "left",
            "refs": 1,
            "is_avc": "true",
            "nal_length_size": "4",
            "r_frame_rate": "30/1",
            "avg_frame_rate": "12330000/444929",
            "time_base": "1/90000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 444929,
            "duration": "4.943656",
            "bit_rate": "4951506",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
            "nb_frames": "137",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "rotate": "90",
                "creation_time": "2019-01-07T15:38:52.000000Z",
                "language": "eng",
                "handler_name": "VideoHandle"
            },
            "side_data_list": [
                {
                    "side_data_type": "Display Matrix",
                    "displaymatrix": "\n00000000:            0       65536           0\n00000001:       -65536           0           0\n00000002:            0           0  1073741824\n",
                    "rotation": -90
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Next is the example of not working video:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001ea0adcd700] sample aspect ratio already set to 1:1, ignoring 'pasp' atom (65536:65536)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'notworking.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2018-12-30T14:20:23.000000Z
    com.android.version: 7.0
  Duration: 00:00:10.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5240 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt470bg/smpte170m), 720x480, 5223 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 3:2, 29.30 fps, 59.94 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      rotate          : 90
      creation_time   : 2018-12-30T14:20:23.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Side data:
      displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 8000 Hz, mono, fltp, 12 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-12-30T14:20:23.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
            "profile": "Baseline",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "20751/1216000",
            "codec_tag_string": "avc1",
            "codec_tag": "0x31637661",
            "width": 720,
            "height": 480,
            "coded_width": 720,
            "coded_height": 480,
            "has_b_frames": 0,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "3:2",
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": 30,
            "color_range": "tv",
            "color_space": "smpte170m",
            "color_transfer": "smpte170m",
            "color_primaries": "bt470bg",
            "chroma_location": "left",
            "refs": 1,
            "is_avc": "true",
            "nal_length_size": "4",
            "r_frame_rate": "60000/1001",
            "avg_frame_rate": "608000/20751",
            "time_base": "1/90000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 914271,
            "duration": "10.158567",
            "bit_rate": "5223363",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
            "nb_frames": "304",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "rotate": "90",
                "creation_time": "2018-12-30T14:20:23.000000Z",
                "language": "eng",
                "handler_name": "VideoHandle"
            },
            "side_data_list": [
                {
                    "side_data_type": "Display Matrix",
                    "displaymatrix": "\n00000000:            0       65536           0\n00000001:       -65536           0           0\n00000002:            0           0  1073741824\n",
                    "rotation": -90
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I cannot see any difference in the videos characteristics. Both are baseline H.264.
Both videos are playing in chrome when I access them via direct links, the problem is on android versions 6, 7, 8.
There is strange thing because when I downloaded that not loading video directly and put in the android app to raw folder and played it directly everything worked perfectly.
I checked if the problem was bandwidth, so I uploaded bigger video about 12Mbs, mp4 as well H.264 Main and then streamed it to the app and it worked like a charm. So I suspect that the issue might be with recording bigger files within my android app.
To stream video I only use MediaPlayer.

That is an example of the video I uploaded and later streamed:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '123456.mp4':


Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2018-01-30T06:50:54.000000Z
  Duration: 00:02:29.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 700 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 571 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-01-30T06:50:54.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file. Created on: 01/29/2018.
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 125 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2018-01-30T06:50:54.000000Z
      handler_name    : ISO Media file. Created on: 01/29/2018.
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
            "profile": "Main",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "1/50",
            "codec_tag_string": "avc1",
            "codec_tag": "0x31637661",
            "width": 1280,
            "height": 720,
            "coded_width": 1280,
            "coded_height": 720,
            "has_b_frames": 1,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "16:9",
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": 31,
            "color_range": "tv",
            "color_space": "bt709",
            "color_transfer": "bt709",
            "color_primaries": "bt709",
            "chroma_location": "left",
            "refs": 1,
            "is_avc": "true",
            "nal_length_size": "4",
            "r_frame_rate": "25/1",
            "avg_frame_rate": "25/1",
            "time_base": "1/90000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 13424400,
            "duration": "149.160000",
            "bit_rate": "571258",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
            "nb_frames": "3729",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "creation_time": "2018-01-30T06:50:54.000000Z",
                "language": "und",
                "handler_name": "ISO Media file. Created on: 01/29/2018."
            }
        }
    ]
}

Is there any chance that my hosting provider uses some kind of software that can manipulate data that is on the server?
```

I also check manually other videos from different websites by inserting links manually in the code to check if MediaPlayer works correctly and every video was playing.

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -i notworking.mp4 -c copy -movflags +faststart hopefullyworkingnow.mp4`

Comment: @llogan Thank you it is working after moving moov atom. Can you please explain me why do shorter recorder videos play like a charm and longer ones have possibly moov atom in the end of file?

Comment: With the moov atom at the end the video has to be downloaded completely before playback can begin. With the long ones you just many not have waited long enough.

Comment: @llogan With the long ones Android MediaPlayer throws an error and stops buffering them, but anyway it's all sorted thanks to your solution. Thank you.